# How to get the amount of days between two dates when the ID is the same?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table which contains following informations (example)

```
ID     START          END
15234  01.05.2019.   13.05.2019
15234  24.05.2019.   28.05.2019
15234  22.06.2019.   26.06.2019
23456  04.04.2019    23.04.2019
23455  07.07.2019.   11.07.2019
23455  02.10.2019.   02.11.2019
```

Now I want to find out

1. If the ID in the rows is the same
2. And if yes if there are 120 days between the starting days
3. If there are 120 or less days between the starting days, I want to calculate, how many days the ID has in average (for example a person has 3 differnet starting and ending days - so, three differnet amount of days in total - I want the average

Which dax Formulars are you recommending me to use to get this information? I am a beginner :)

Kind regards Maria

Comment: 120 days for those first 3 rows with same id? what if there are more than 120 days in total? what if another row (4th) with id 15234  is there at the end?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your questions. I want to check if there are 120 days or less inbetween the lines - this mean when there are three rows for a ID, I want to check if there are 120 days or less between the starting day of row 1 and 2 and row 2 and 3. If there are more than 120 days, I want that a blank row is shown in the new column - I only want the data where 120 days are between the starting days IF the ID is the same. If there is another row with ID 15234 at the end, I would sort the data to show all the data from one ID before analyzing the dataset.

Comment: much clear now. can you please explain what you mean by "starting day of row 1 and 2 and row 2 and 3"? you can explain this by the value of first three rows. And please mention which date (besides id) will be there in your ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your questions. For example in this dataset in the first row the start is 01. May 2019. I want to check if the ID is the same, which is the case but is there a dax formula to define this in a big data set? In the next step I want to analyse if between 01.05.2019 (row 1) and 24.05.2019 (row 2) are 120 days, and between 24.05.2019 and 22.06.2019 also 120 or less days. I don't understand the last question unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. So there will be a ordering  on your data set on column - id and start... right?

Comment: Yes that would be my plan. I would first order my data in the column - ID and then start the analysis via dax formula. Thank you very much for your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my so far understanding, I have created some custom/index columns. In the following image, you will find one of them holding the date difference with previous row's start date for the same ID. Please check and let me know value in "date_difference" column will help you in your further calculation or not. If the answer is yes, I will share code for all columns.

> Column Index created for sorting the data only.

[image]

**Steps for achieving your required output:**

**Step-1:** In Power Query Editor, first create a custom column to generate the actual date formatted value from START. The script is as shown in the image below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Change the data type of newly created column as date time and the output will be as below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Now order column ID first ascending and then newly added column"converted_start+date" ascending as well.

**Step-4:** Now add an index column as shown in the picture below-

[image]

**Step-5:** Now get back to report with clicking "Apply & Close" button.

**Step-6:** Create the date_difference measure now with this below code-

```
date_difference = 

VAR current_id = your_table_name[ID]
VAR current_start_date = your_table_name[converted_start_date]

VAR prev_row_start_date = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[converted_start_date]),
    FILTER(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[ID] = current_id 
            && your_table_name[converted_start_date] < current_start_date
    )
)

RETURN DATEDIFF(
    prev_row_start_date,
    your_table_name[converted_start_date],
    DAY
)
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! This looks great and the column "date difference" will help me. Can you share the dax code for this calculated column? And is there a dax formular which can calculate the average days for every ID? For example ID 15234 has 23 and 29 days difference. This would mean 23+29 = 52 - - > average 26 days (52:2 (values). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks amazing and is exactly what I looked for. I am happy that you helped me out. I will try this formular tomorrow at work with Power BI. Thank you very much again! :)

Comment: You are most welcome @MariaCaeser. Please let me know if you face any issue. About average calculation, do you need 1 row per ID with the average? Or wants to keep all 3 rows with the same average value in all rows in a new column? Please let me know....

Comment: Thank you very much. I will let you know if I had any issues. For the average: I need one row per ID. The other rows can be shown blank. Thank you very much :)